# What are the irreducible representations of $\mathbf{10}\otimes \mathbf{3}$ in $SU(3)$

Tags: lie-algebras, tensors, tensor-decomposition

Since, a rank-3 tensor has 10 components and a rank-1 tensor has 3 components in $SU(3)$, I know that we are searching for the different irreducible representations of the tensor $v_{ijk}w_{l}$.

The fully symmetric part is equivalent to a rank-4 totally symmetric tensor with $v_{(ijk}w_{l)} = x_{ijkl}$. This will have 15 components.

But, I am not sure how to account for the rest 15.

$$\mathbf{10 \otimes 3 = 15 \ \oplus \ ? }$$